# How can we get name of the method which has failed assertion

Tags: junit

Is there a way to programmatically get name of the method which fails asserttion in a JUnit test case ?
i.e. if Assert.assertTrue(ClassName.methodName) in @Test fails, I can only get the name of @Test method which has the assertion but not able to get methodName which failed assertion.
We have close to 300 JUnit tests each having their own @BeforeClass, @Before, @Test, @After and @AfterClass methods and want to log the method name which failed assertion.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but hopefully still helpful. Consider re-writing your tests so that each test method contains a single assertion. Then the name of the test and the method that contains the (failed) assertion is identical. With this approach you also get other benefits, which are out of scope here.

Comment: Beyond what C-Otto wrote ... keep in mind that the idea of unit tests is to help you isolate/resolve your problems **quickly**. So, if your setup is so complicated that you need so much different "prep/teardown" code ... maybe, just maybe that tells you that you should step back for a second and think how to you could "improve" your tests in a way that makes them ... better at pointing out problems to you.

Comment: Actually, we are using JUnit to automate regression test scenarios (!!) We already have automated over 300 scenarios and re-writing all the tests would be expensive. <br> We wanted to save time in identifying test failures by specifically logging the failed methods so that we don't have to go over the entire log file to find cause of failure.<br> From assertion failure stack trace, I can get the line in the script containing the failure. Is there a way to get the contents of that java file line from the executable jar ? I feel this is the only option left.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/swfsm/junit-fail-logger.
 It is an annotation processor that in compile time scans methods annotated with `org.junit.Test` and wraps assertions with try catch block in order to log failed assertion.

 So

```
assertTrue(myMethod(""));
```

will be transformed to

```
try {
    assertTrue(myMethod());
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    System.err.println("assertTrue(myMethod())")
    throw(e);
}
```

Method which is invoked for logging is configurable and may be any static method accepting `String` parameter (parameter value is configurable as well).